# MySQL DISTINCT won't work when certain columns are SELECTed

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I got a mysterious behaviour using DISTINCT on a MySQL table and can't figure it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `deal_hash`,`city_name` 
  FROM `a` 
 WHERE `city_name` = 'b'
```

...will show me the desired output with DISTINCT on **deal_hash**.  I can also add any other column to the select and it will work only in two cases DISTINCT will fail

```
SELECT DISTINCT `deal_hash`,`deal_link` 
  FROM `a` 
 WHERE `city_name` = 'b'
```

AND

```
SELECT DISTINCT `deal_hash`,`loaded_at` 
  FROM `a` 
 WHERE `city_name` = 'b'
```

`deal_link` is a varchar(255) and loaded_at a INT(20).

Comment: `distinct` applies to all columns in the `select` list not just the first one. Is that the source of your confusion? If not please explain what "DISTINCT will fail" means.

Comment: `DISTINCT` shows distinct **rows**.  PostgreSQL is the only DB I know of that supports `DISTINCT ON`, applied to a particular column.

Comment: Thanks that exactly was the problem, wasnt aware of the complete behaviour of DISTINCT, if now someone posts this as an answer i would accept :)

Comment: @OMG - I prefer your wording so will leave that to you!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct` `select`s `distinct` **rows**. It is not specific to the following column.

Try using [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) instead:

```
select deal_hash, min(deal_link)
from a
where city_name = 'b'
group by deal_hash
```

or

```
select deal_hash, max(loaded_at)
from a
where city_name = 'b'
group by deal_hash
```

Answer (score 3):

`DISTINCT` shows distinct ***rows*** (of column values).

PostgreSQL is the only DB I know of that supports DISTINCT ON, applied to a particular column.